# Java large for performance

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, numbers

I have to find the thousandth number (excluding numbers 3, 4, 7) but it's taking a long time, about 9 seconds to find out how to improve performance.

```java
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class FirstChallange {

    private static int removedNumbers;
    private static int numberQuantity;
    private static int lastNumberFound; 
    private static int cont;
    private static int pos3;
    private static int pos4;
    private static int pos7;    

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();  

        removedNumbers = 0;
        numberQuantity = 10000000;


        for (cont = 1; removedNumbers <= numberQuantity; cont++) {      
            String str = new String(); 
            str = String.valueOf(cont);     

            pos3 = str.indexOf("3");
            pos4 = str.indexOf("4");
            pos7 = str.indexOf("7");

            if((pos3 == -1) && (pos4 == -1) && (pos7 == -1)) {
                removedNumbers++; 
                if(removedNumbers == numberQuantity){ // can not find numbers (3, 4, 7)
                    lastNumberFound = cont; 
                }
            } 
        }       

        DecimalFormat dfmt = new DecimalFormat("0");

        System.out.println(dfmt.format(lastNumberFound)); 

        long fim  = System.currentTimeMillis();   
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("ss.SSS").format(new Date(fim - inicio)));  


    }
}
```

Is converting numbers into string and removing them with indexOf the best mode? or is there anything better than indexOf like RabinKarp?

Expected result: 180999565 in 5/4 seconds

Comment: If your code works and needs to be optimized, you should probably post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should think about the problem in an entirely different way. Out of every decade of natural numbers, 7 are OK: if you have to tell the 20th, it should be 29. Can you work out the numbers for 100 naturals, 1000, one million? The details like the 40th OK number *not* being 58 (but 88). Once programmed, a 2019 computing device should take milliseconds, if that.

Comment: (Errm. *I have to find the thousandth number* ↔ `numberQuantity = 10000000`?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on MrSmith's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55745978/15472), you can observe that, once you translate the expected output, `180999565`, using the lookup  tables and function below ...

```
                       // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
static int b10_to_b7[] = {0, 1, 2,-1,-1, 3, 4,-1, 5, 6}; // avoids 3, 4 and 7
static int b7_to_b10[] = {0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9,-1,-1,-1}; // undoes above permutation 

// extracts digits in base b, replacing them according to p
static long permuteDigits(long input, long base, int[] p) {
    long output = 0;
    long shift = 1;
    while (input > 0) {
       int digit = (int)(input % base);
       input /= base;
       output += p[digit] * shift;
       shift *= base;
    }
    return output;
}

// converts input digits in base ibase into obase
static long changeBase(long input, long ibase, long obase) {
    long output = 0;
    long shift = 1;
    while (input > 0) {
       int digit = (int)(input % ibase);
       input /= ibase;
       output += digit * shift;
       shift *= obase;
    }
    return output;
}


permuteDigits(180999565L, 10, b10_to_b7); // 150666343
changeBase(150666343L, 10, 7);            // 10000000  !!
```

So, using the same functions, you can find your result directly by reversing the operations:

```
changeBase(10000000L, 7, 10);             // 150666343
permuteDigits(150666343L, 10, b7_to_b10); // 180999565
```

And this takes only `O(log(n))` operations, which is much quicker than any iterative approach. Your original code was `O(n log(n))`

Note that you can optimize my code, by merging both functions. But that will win you only about a x2 speed improvement: nothing as drastic as the x10M improvement from avoiding iteration.

Answer (score 3):

You should think about the problem in a different way.

"Generate all numbers below *numberQuantity* that do not contain 3, 4, 7"

Or with other words:
"Create numbers only containing 0,1,2,5,6,8,9 as digits".

These are 7 different digits.

So one approach could be increment a counter starting with 1 and convert it to a represenattion base 7 where you map each digit like this:

```
0->0
1->1
2->2
3->5
4->6
5->8
6->9
```

Comment: How would this work, the counter is one and we map it to two? So one is now missing in the sequence? I understand what your aiming for but do not understand your mapping..

Comment: (The lowest unwanted digit is 3, not 1.)

Comment: Downvoted for suggesting *find the nth number* means *Generate all numbers below numberQuantity*.

Comment: I built on your idea of base-conversion to get an O(log(n)) answer. Note that, as @greybeard observes, it is a lot better to perform direct base conversion than to generate all `n` numbers before arriving at the correct one. Iterating is `n` times worse.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a need to search?  Working on the comments above, that there are 7 digits, there is a much more efficient direct method, which is to generate the base 7 digits, then remapping them according to the exclusion scheme.

See below for the complete program text which implements three strategies: A faster "search" which uses a byte array instead of strings.  This is about the same as the original algorithm, but should be much faster.  A base 7 conversion using java formatting, and a direct base 7 conversion, which most likely best satisfies the original problem requirements.

Here is just the "Direct" implementation.  This implementation generates the target number as a base 7 number, then remaps the digits according to the scheme to exclude digits 3, 4, and 7:

```
public static int findNumberDirect(int index) {
    int base = 7;

    byte[] digits = new byte[10];  // Storage for the base 7 digits.

    // Convert to base 7 by generating digits for each power of 7.

    for ( int nextDigit = 0; index > 0; nextDigit++ ) {
        int nextRem = index % base;
        index = index / base;

        digits[nextDigit] = (byte) nextRem;
    }

    // Remap the digits from base 7 to base 10 with exclusions.
    // This could be done in the prior loop.  I've kept this as
    // a separate step for clarity.

    int number = 0;

    int numDigits = digits.length;
    for ( int nextDigit = 0; nextDigit < numDigits; nextDigit++ ) {
        number *= 10;
        number += DIGIT_MAPPING[ digits[ numDigits - nextDigit - 1 ] ];
    }

    return number;
}
```

Here are timings as output by the program:

```
Index [        1 ] Search [        1 ] [   2100 (ns) ] Convert [        1 ] [   4500 (ns) ] Direct [        1 ] [   1300 (ns) ] 
Index [        4 ] Search [        6 ] [   1400 (ns) ] Convert [        6 ] [   1900 (ns) ] Direct [        6 ] [   1000 (ns) ] 
Index [       10 ] Search [       15 ] [   1900 (ns) ] Convert [       15 ] [   2000 (ns) ] Direct [     15 ] [   1000 (ns) ] 
Index [      100 ] Search [      202 ] [  26300 (ns) ] Convert [      202 ] [   2100 (ns) ] Direct [      202 ] [   1000 (ns) ] 
Index [     1000 ] Search [     2929 ] [  98300 (ns) ] Convert [     2929 ] [   2100 (ns) ] Direct [     2929 ] [   1000 (ns) ] 
Index [    10000 ] Search [    61106 ] [ 694300 (ns) ] Convert [    61106 ] [   2100 (ns) ] Direct [    61106 ] [    900 (ns) ]
```

Here is the complete program text:

```
package my.tests;

public class NumberCounter {

    // Find the thousandth number (excluding numbers 3, 4, 7).

    public static final String USAGE_TEXT = "Usage: " + NumberCounter.class.getName() + " index*";

    public static final int MAX_INDEX = 10000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for ( int argNo = 0; argNo < args.length; argNo++ ) {
            String indexText = args[argNo];
            int index = Integer.parseInt(indexText);
            if ( index <= 0 ) {
                System.out.println("Error: Index [ " + indexText + " ] is less than 1.");
                return;
            } else if ( index > MAX_INDEX ) {
                System.out.println("Error: Index [ " + indexText + " ] is greater than " + Integer.toString(MAX_INDEX) + ".");
                return;
            }

            long searchStart = System.nanoTime();
            int searchNumber = findNumberSearch(index);
            long searchEnd = System.nanoTime();

            long convertStart = System.nanoTime();
            int convertNumber = findNumberConvert(index);
            long convertEnd = System.nanoTime();

            long directStart = System.nanoTime();
            int directNumber = findNumberDirect(index);
            long directEnd = System.nanoTime();

            System.out.println("Index [ " + formatAmount((long) index) + " ]" +
                               " Search [ " + formatAmount(searchNumber) + " ] [ " + formatDuration(searchEnd, searchStart) + " ]" +
                               " Convert [ " + formatAmount(convertNumber) + " ] [ " + formatDuration(convertEnd, convertStart) + " ]" +
                               " Direct [ " + formatAmount(directNumber) + " ] [ " + formatDuration(directEnd, directStart) + " ]");                               
        }
    }

    public static String formatDuration(long end, long start) {
        return String.format("%6d (ns)", Long.valueOf(end - start));
    }

    public static String formatAmount(long amount) {
        return String.format("%8d", Long.valueOf(amount));
    }

    private final static byte[] DIGIT_MAPPING = { 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9 };

    public static int findNumberSearch(int index) {
        byte[] digits = new byte[10];
        int numDigits = digits.length;

        for ( int nextNumber = 0; nextNumber < index; nextNumber++ ) {
            for ( int nextDigit = 0; nextDigit < numDigits; nextDigit++ ) {
                int digitOffset = numDigits - nextDigit - 1;
                byte digit = digits[digitOffset];
                if ( digit == 6 ) {
                    digit = 0;
                } else {
                    digit++;
                }
                digits[digitOffset] = digit;
                if ( digit != 0 ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        int number = 0;

        for ( int nextDigit = 0; nextDigit < numDigits; nextDigit++ ) {
            number *= 10;
            number += DIGIT_MAPPING[ digits[nextDigit] ];
        }

        return number;
    }

    public static int findNumberConvert(int index) {
        String numberText = Integer.toString(index, 7);

        int number = 0;

        int numDigits = numberText.length();
        for ( int nextDigit = 0; nextDigit < numDigits; nextDigit++ ) {
            number *= 10;
            number += DIGIT_MAPPING[ numberText.charAt(nextDigit) - '0' ];
        }

        return number;
    }

    public static int findNumberDirect(int index) {
        int base = 7;

        byte[] digits = new byte[10];

        for ( int nextDigit = 0; index > 0; nextDigit++ ) {
            int nextRem = index % base;
            index = index / base;

            digits[nextDigit] = (byte) nextRem;
        }

        int number = 0;

        int numDigits = digits.length;
        for ( int nextDigit = 0; nextDigit < numDigits; nextDigit++ ) {
            number *= 10;
            number += DIGIT_MAPPING[ digits[ numDigits - nextDigit - 1 ] ];
        }

        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: I seem to have re-implemented your answer before coming back and reading it completely. Your answer can be improved by first stating how you answer the problem, and why your answer works; and then, later on, providing the benchmark. The insight for the direct conversion is much more interesting (and currently buried at the bottom of your code)

Comment: Yeah, that was a bit terse.  I've made a number of edits.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you do an indexOf, you are looping inside a String to see if it contains a character.

Then you are doing 3 "indexOf", so at each turn of loop your processing in that part is multiplied by 3.

We can consider putting these 3 checks together in a single loop, and thus improve performance, for example by creating a method that emulates "indexOf" but where you pass the 3 validations:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class FirstChallange {

    private static int removedNumbers=0;
    private static int numberQuantity;
    private static int lastNumberFound; 
    private static int cont;

    private static char three = '3';
    private static char four = '4';
    private static char seven = '7';

    private static SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("ss.SSS");
    private static DecimalFormat dfmt = new DecimalFormat("0");

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();  

        numberQuantity = 10000000;

        String str; 

        for (cont = 1; removedNumbers <= numberQuantity; cont++) {      

            //Faster way to create String
            str = "" + cont;

            if(!contains(str.toCharArray())) {
                removedNumbers++; 
                if(removedNumbers == numberQuantity){ // can not find numbers (3, 4, 7)
                    lastNumberFound = cont; 
                }
            } 
        }

        System.out.println(dfmt.format(lastNumberFound)); 

        long fim  = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(sf.format(new Date(fim - inicio)));  

    }

    public static boolean contains(char[] chars) {

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
             if(chars[i] == three) {
                return true;
            } else if (chars[i] == four) {
                return true;
            } else if(chars[i] == seven) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

The **contains** method I've created here, checks if the character we don't want is present, and if it is, we don't check anymore and we return true.

I've reduced the performance by 3 or 4 seconds.